# 2 approachs for creating a jquery dialog.

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have 2 different approaches to create a dialog with Jquery

This one don´t work:

```
 var options = "{width: 1024, height: 600, modal: true, buttons: { Cancelar: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } }, draggable: false, resizeble: false}";

$('#UserSettings').dialog(options);
```

and this one works fine:

```
$('#UserSettings').dialog({ width: 1024, height: 600, modal: true, buttons: { Cancelar: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } }, draggable: false, resizeble: false });
```

Can´t figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes for the options in the first one. The argument to the dialog is an object and not string.

```
var options = {  
        width: 1024, 
        height: 600, 
        modal: true, 
        buttons: { 
           Cancelar: function () { 
              $(this).dialog('close'); 
           } 
        },
        draggable: false, 
        resizeble: false
 };
```

Comment: @user1827417 If it worked, please don't forget to upvote/accept this is as an answer. (Green tick mark on the left to accept)